# connexion problem with my emulator android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, ping

I have a problem on android studio, I would like to ping an external router on adb shell from my emulator but it doesn't work. However, the routing table tells me that I am going through the gateway. When I ping the emulator's gateway, everything goes fine. On the other hand, when I ping the address of the external router, no packets are received. How do I make the ping work?

Here's the network configuration:
Emulator ip Address: 192.168.232.2
Emulator Gateway: 192.168.232.1
Emulator mask: 255.255.248.0
Dns 1: 10.0.2.3
Dns 2: 192.168.1.3 (Dns that allows me to join the external terminal)
External terminal IP address: 192.168.1.1

i tried to ping the router but it doesn't work
Here's the result of the ping :

```bash
$ ping -c 1 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Here's the route

```bash
1|generic_x86_arm:/ $ /system/bin/ip route
192.168.232.0/21 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.232.2
```